# When to use Svelte's use:action vs onMount and onDestroy?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

If we have something like a `Tooltip` class that needs to instantiate an instance, update that instance, and destroy that instance in sync with when the component is mounted, updated, and destroyed (as demonstrated in the code below), there seems to be two patterns for doing this.

1. Using `use:action`
2. Using `onMount` and `onDestroy`

The `use:action` method seems cleaner, but aside from that, are there any underlying differences between these two methods that would make one preferred over the other in certain situations?

Example of using `use:action`:

```
<script>
  import Tooltip from './tooltip'

  export let text = ''

  function initTooltip(node, text) {
    const tooltip = Tooltip(node)
    tooltip.text = text
    return {
      update(text) {
        tooltip.text = text
      },
      destroy() {
        tooltip.destroy()
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<div use:initTooltip={text}>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Example of using `onMount` and `onDestroy`:

```
<script>
  import Tooltip from './tooltip'
  import { onMount, onDestroy } from 'svelte'

  export let text = ''

  let node
  let tooltip

  onMount(() => {
    tooltip = Tooltip(node)
    tooltip.text = text
  })

  $: if (tooltip && tooltip.text !== text) {
    tooltip.text = text
  }

  onDestroy(() => {
    if (tooltip) {
      tooltip.destroy()
    }
  })
</script>

<div bind:this={node}>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your tooltip a Component or a function in a js file?

Comment: @voscausa, `Tooltip` is a class in a js file. Calling `Tooltip(node)` will attach some event listeners to that node and return an instance that has a `.destroy()` method, that when called, removes those event listeners.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If it's behaviour that you can imagine needing to reuse among multiple components, or if it's something that you can imagine applying to an element inside an `{#if ...}` block (for example), then it probably belongs in an action.

It it's something that 'belongs' to the component itself, rather than a specific element, then it's probably more of a lifecycle thing.

In this case, my tendency would probably be to use an action.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, Rich!