# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'notifyPlugins') - chart.js

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas, chart.js, svelte

Why is my chart attempting to read notifyPlugins('beforeDestroy') when navigating away from the page of the chart?

I have a plugins file, a svelte action and a main file [ChartMetrics.svelte] (where the action is used). The current behaviour is that the chart loads completely fine in the main page, but when navigating to another page I am met with the notifyPlugins error. I have added the most relevant code from my project, as the entire codebase is quite large so would be unable to add it to a codesandbox. Has anyone recieved this error with notifyPlugins before when working with chart.js? If there is any more code you need to see let me know.

console error:

```
chart.js:6171 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'notifyPlugins')
    at destroy (chart.js:6171:1)
    at Object.destroy [as d] (ChartMetrics.svelte:454:1)
    at Object.destroy [as d] (Div.svelte:127:1)
    at destroy_component (index.mjs:1974:1)
    at Object.destroy [as d] (ChartMetrics.svelte:127:1)
    at Object.destroy [as d] (ChartMetrics.svelte:535:1)
    at destroy_component (index.mjs:1974:1)
    at Object.destroy [as d] (EffectiveMaterialAssetsMetricsContainer.svelte:71:1)
    at Object.destroy [as d] (MetricWrapper.svelte:133:1)
    at Object.destroy [as d] (MetricWrapper.svelte:308:1)
```

chart.js (line 6171):

```
destroy() {
   this.notifyPlugins('beforeDestroy');
   ....
}
```

ChartMetrics (line 454):

```
        d: function destroy(detaching) {
            if (detaching) detach_dev(div0);
            if_blocks[current_block_type_index].d();
            destroy_component(tooltipinfo);
            destroy_component(anchor);
            if (detaching) detach_dev(t3);
            if (detaching) detach_dev(div1);
            mounted = false;
            dispose();
        }
```

ChartMetrics line 454 (image):
[image: chartMetrics]

plugins.ts:

```
export function textPlugin(value: number, theme: Theme) {
  return {
    id: "chartTextPlugin",
    // Plugin for writing text in middle of chart
    beforeDraw: function (chart: ChartType) {
      plugin that draws some text on a chart.js chart
    },
  }
}

export function curvePlugin() {
  // Curve edges of donut
  return {
    id: "chartCurvePlugin",
    afterUpdate: function (chart: ChartType) {
      // some code to curve the edges of the chart.js chart
      }
    },
    afterDraw: function (chart: ChartType) {
      // some more code to do same as above
    },
  }
}
```

add-chart.ts (svelte action)

```
export const addChart = (node: HTMLElement, params: ChartProps): ChartGauge => {
  const text = textPlugin(params.value, params.theme)
  const curve = curvePlugin()
  const backgroundColor = mapTypeToColor(params.theme)

  return new Chart(node, {
    type: "doughnut",
    data: {
      datasets: [
        {
          //label: params.caption,
          data: [params.value, 100 - params.value],
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          borderColor: ["rgba(255, 255, 255 ,1)"],
          borderWidth: 0,
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      rotation: -90,
      cutout: "85%",
      circumference: 180,
      radius: "85%",
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      aspectRatio: 3,
    },
    plugins: [text, curve],
  })
}
```

ChartMetrics.svelte

```
{#if value >= 0 && value <= 100}
  <CardDiv p={4} pl={4} pr={4}>
    <div class="metrics-header">
      <h3>
        Controls -
        {#if titleUrl}
          <Anchor href={titleUrl} size={14}>{title}</Anchor>
        {:else}
          <span>{title}</span>
        {/if}
        <TooltipInfo content={tooltipContent} id="info" width="small" />
      </h3>
      <Anchor href={assuranceUrl} size={14}>View Assurance</Anchor>
    </div>
    <div class="chart">
      <canvas
        id="chart"
        data-test-id="chart"
        use:addChart={{ value, theme }}
        style="height:100%;width:100%;"
      />
    </div>
  </CardDiv>
{:else}
  <MetricsError message="Chart Metrics Widget Error: Invalid value." />
{/if}
```

Comment: At a first glance, this doesn't appear to be caused by the plugin. It seems that in `ChartMetrics.svelte` at line 454 there's a call to chart's `destroy` that makes `this` `undefined` inside the function, something like `chart.destroy.call()` instead of `chart.destroy()`

Comment: Yep thats in chartjserror picture I had linked. Would this be an issue with chartjs then?

Comment: No, I think the cause is the way that code from the svelte component `ChartMetrics` calls `destroy`. Can't you post what's there at around line 454?

Comment: Sure, i edited my question to put the full code where destroy is called.

Comment: Now we have the problem to know how `d` is called so that `this` is `undefined`. Is this component your code, or from an imported library (I couldn't find anything on google)? You may consider adding a functioning/simplified version of your code for full debug to a stackblitz or codesandbox. Also, just as a friendly note, for future posts on SO, people here tend to react unpleasantly to code put in images, there's also a [meta reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16466946) about that.

Comment: Yep its a component of my code. I will edit the answer with as much of the code as i can and replace images with code

Comment: I've updated the question, my codebase is a bit too large to put it into a working codesandbox env, so ive added to the question. If theres any other code youd like to see let me know, still havent progressed at all with respect to this error.

Comment: I'll tell you how I'd proceed if I could debug the code: I'd put a `console.log(this)` in `d()` just before `destroy` and try to see which property of `this` is the chart instance (or maybe `this` is a subclass of `Chart`, or possibly there's another way to get hold of the chart instance) and modify `destroy()` to `destroy.call(chartInstance)`. The chart instance is an object that has such properties as `canvas`, `chartArea`, `boxes`

Comment: So the d() function isnt actually a part of my ChartMetrics.svelte, what I see in the ChartMetrics.svelte in the browser inspector is very different to what I have in my IDE. The full ChartMetrics.svelte file from my IDE is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ay4ars?file=src%2FChartMetrics.svelte and this is the browser inspector version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ay4ars?file=src%2FChartMetrics.svelte,src%2FChartMetrics_browser.svelte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this patch of a solution: in `add-chart.ts` instead of

```js
return new Chart(node, {
.....
});
```

use

```js
const chart = new Chart(node, {
    .....
});
chart.destroy = chart.destroy.bind(chart);
return chart;
```

A more svelte-idiomatic way might be

```js
return {
   ...chart,
   destroy(){
      chart.destroy();
   }
}
```

but that would probably need some typescript acrobatics to pass type-checking.

Comment: @ou9hwq93weiq please let me know what's happening if you make the first change; we are on trial and error path here

Comment: Hey sorry I just got back to the computer. I just tried out your solution and it works! Could you explain whats happening with the svelte-idiomatic way? Are you ovewriting the destroy function for the ChartMetrics file and replacing it with the charts destroy function?

Comment: Just to clarify, both methods work but just want to understand whats going on when you say "chart.destroy = chart.destroy.bind(chart)"?

Comment: So the problem was that the default destroy method generated by svelte (in your generated [file](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ay4ars?file=src%2FChartMetrics.svelte,src%2FChartMetrics_browser.svelte) at line 381) just took the `destroy` method  from the chart instance and called it with a `undefined` context (`this`), see the [source code](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/src/runtime/internal/utils.ts#L189).

Comment: The first method uses `bind`, so with that, the `destroy` function is always linked to the chart instance, no matter how it is called, `this` will be that instance.

Comment: The second method is to provide an explicit `destroy` to svelte, instead of the default one. It's basically the same thing, svelte will call this method, but no matter how it is called, it takes care that the call to the chart's `destroy` is correct, that is `chart.destroy()`, not just `destroy`.

Comment: I said that this seemed more idiomatic to me, since I saw in many examples that the object that's returned by the initialization function in a `use:` scenario (as is the case in your code) has only an `update` and a `destroy`, the rest of the created instance (the chart.js instance in your code) works by itself, but is not exposed (you may explore that in full if it works for you). Look for instance at the first example in the question from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068865/when-to-use-sveltes-useaction-vs-onmount-and-ondestroy).

Comment: I see an analogy with my using chart.js in a vanilla html+js environment -- in most cases I don't need to declare a variable `const chart = new Chart(....`, it's enough to just construct the chart instance `new Chart(....`, the important thing is to provide the correct initialization data, then it will work by itself, there's no use for a reference to it. Well, in your case, you need a `destroy` method (I don't know if an  `update` is actually needed) so maybe it's possible that your `addChart` function could return just the `destroy`, that is without  the `...chart` part in the second version